# Quiero poner fecha actual en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

No soy experto en PHP asi que me consegui un codigo para crear un chorcote el cual me permita poner fecha actualizada del dia dentro de un articulo en Wordpress. El codigo es el siguiente y lo puse dentro de funciones php:

```php
function displayTodaysDate( $atts )

{

return date(get_option('date_format'));

}

add_shortcode( 'datetoday', 'displayTodaysDate');
```

Pero el codigo tiene un problema, ya que saca el mes en ingles y yo lo quiero tener en español. Por favor alguien me podria indicar que tengo que modificar para que el mes salga en Español.

Mi wordpress esta configurado a español, el servidor tambien.

Comment: Puedes usar [`date_i18n()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/) que te mostrará la fecha en el idioma en el que tengas configurado tu WP. Sería simplemente hacer algo como esto: `return date_i18n(get_option('date_format'));`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`date_i18n()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/)  que te mostrará la fecha en el idioma en el que tengas configurado tu WordPress.

Sería simplemente hacer algo como esto:

```
return date_i18n(get_option('date_format'));
```